# Prove that there exists a unique set $T$ such that for every set $S$, $S\cup{T}=S$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Prove that there exists a unique set $T$ such that for every set $S$, $S\cup{T}=S$.

So far I have assumed that there exist two sets, $T1$ and $T2$ such that
$S\cup{T1}=S$ and $S\cup{T2}=S$.

Not sure where to go about this now, any help would be appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By taking  $S=\varnothing $ we get $\varnothing\cup T=\varnothing $, hence $T=\varnothing $, thus proving uniqueness.

Answer (score 2):

$$T_1 \overset{(a)}= T_1 \cup T_2 = T_2 \cup T_1 \overset{(b)}= T_2$$
where at $(a)$, we used that $S = S \cup T_1$ for every set $S$, and at $(b)$, we used that $ S \cup T_2 =S $ for every  set $S$.

Comment: This proves uniqueness. Hopefully the OP can figure out _existence_ on his own.

Answer (score 0):

From your working we have
$$S \,\,\cup\,\, T1=S \,\,\cup\,\, T2\,\,(=S)$$
$$(S \,\,\cup\,\, T1)\setminus S=(S \,\,\cup\,\, T2)\setminus S$$
$$\therefore T1=T2$$
So, we have that $T$ is a unique set. We can see that it must also be the null set - $\varnothing$ - as its union with the set $S$ does not add any elements to $S$.